# Why does a $rootScope.$watch return a value multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular app which has a controller with a function that watches a variable as it changes in the rootscope; that is,

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$watch('someVar', function() {
        console.log($rootScope.someVar);
    });
}
```

For some reason though, if I change $rootScope.someVar to "Hello", I get the following console output

```
> Hello
> Hello
> Hello
```

Why is it doing this? I am writing a program which parses large datafiles, and if I could get a three fold increase in performance, my life would be a lot happier.

Comment: could you share the angular version you are using and complete code in plunker of fiddle demo  see the plunker demo it is getting called only one time http://plnkr.co/edit/Qt84NZlCfjywGdaChDiD?p=preview

Comment: I am using 1.0.7. Would you accept a link to c9? https://c9.io/lucas_simon994/spreadsheet/workspace/spreadsheet/index.html#/

Answer (score 2):

If a side effect of a watch results in a variable change, the watch gets called again until  all changes are resolved.

So if the action that results in the watch getting triggered (the action that changes someVar) results in other actions that also update someVar, there can be a cascade (up to 10 times before angular says enough?)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem watching a variable on the **$rootScope** from a **child controller** and 'opening' more times this controller. For each times I open the controller seems that angular add a different watcher and when the variable changes the watcher fires more times.

I solved this problem adding inside the parent controller (AppCtrl) the watcher and broadcasting a custom event, while on the child controller (ChildCtrl) listening that event:

AppCtrl:

```
$rootScope.$watch('myVar', function(myVar){
    if(myVar){
        var obj = doSomethingWithMyVar(myVar);
        $scope.$broadcast('myEventName', obj);
    }
});
```

ChildCtrl:

```
$scope.$on('myEventName', function(event, obj){
    console.log(obj);
});
```